# Composition root for a singleton WCF service

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am usually working with WCF services that uses [single instance context mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx). Also service contract and behavior is in a WCF service Library.

If the service is hosted as a Windows Service or a Web service, they get their own projects that references the WCF service library. I like to keep this WCF service library running (for simply debugging with WCF Test Client) but it requires [too much effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058761/can-i-use-wcffacility-with-wcf-test-client) when I try to resolve dependencies through the behavior class.

Using Castle Windsor, I also have to make additional configuration for [Castle Windsor WCF Integration Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.WCF-Facility-Registration.ashx). I am just trying to resolve the object graph on service startup and I feel like it shouldn't be this hard.

I thought, since behavior instance is created only once I should be able to use it as the composition root. I can provide all dependencies using a single object and resolve it from the container like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class SampleService : ISampleService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IServiceManager _serviceManager;
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public SampleService()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        _container.Install(new ServiceInstaller());

        _serviceManager = _container.Resolve<IServiceManager>();
    }

    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return _serviceManager.GetMessage();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I know it's a bad idea to explicitly ask the container to resolve a dependency but this saves me from so much trouble. I get to keep the default WCF configuration, I can run the WCF service library for debugging since I have a default constructor now. I also don't have to use Castle Windsor WCF integration Facility which was missing documentation last time I checked.

I guess Castle Windsor WCF integration Facility offers more features but I just want to resolve the dependencies. Is this approach likely to cause some problems? I haven't seen anyone do it like this so I would like to know if this would be legitimate use.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2455039/126014